# Azure Functions #r is only allowed in scripts

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to get a ConnectionString in an Azure Functions App. I've created a new Functions App in Visual Studio, and was using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup) sample, which says I need to add this line to the Function.cs:

```
#r "System.Configuration"
```

But when I try it, IntelliSense says that

```
#r is only allowed in scripts
```

Build fails too.

[image: IntelliSense error]

Already tried renaming the file to .csx, without success.
According to the developer reference, it should work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio is creating a project which gets precompiled before being run as a Function App. Effectively, it's just a C# class library which references Functions SDK NuGet package.

To reference another library or NuGet packages, just use the usual ways to do so for class libraries: Add Reference or Add NuGet Package.

Thus, no `#r` directive is needed.

Comment: That's great, but `System.Configuration` is not a nuget, only an assembly, which doesn't got precompiled... Problem doesn't got solved with using a nuget package containing `System.Configuration` (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager)... I just gave up on getting out a connection string from appsettings and just added as a plain setting.

Comment: Just Add Reference to that assembly

Comment: @Mikhail I can't add an assembly from the framework. The project is targeting .NET Standard 2.0. How can I do this? It's not a NuGet and it's not a script. Do I need to manually download a DLL or what?

Comment: I am having this same issue and have not found a resolution to include custom DLLs from normal CS files. CSX #r does work to reference include DLLs within bin directory. Any documentation on this for normal visual studio published cs azure function projects for version 1.x (.NET framework)?